# Get id from inserted data

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

My data is being inserted via ajax and then in the php function 
I want as soon as data has been inserted the user can click on a preview button,
and will be redirected to a dynamic page where data will be pulled from the db
based on the id. At the moment the id in the query string is getting nothing.

I have:

```
   <?php

       class Campaign {

     public $int_campaign_id;


    public function Insert($title,$desc,$cat,$type){

            $_title = $this->db->mysqli->real_escape_string($title);
            $_desc = $this->db->mysqli->real_escape_string($desc);
            $_cat = $this->db->mysqli->real_escape_string($cat);
            $_type = $this->db->mysqli->real_escape_string($type);
            $sql = "INSERT INTO mytable VALUES(NULL,
                     '{$_title}','{$_desc}','{$_cat}','{$_type}', NOW())";

                $result = $this->db->mysqli->query($sql);

                if(!$result)
                {
                        throw new Exception("Query failed!" . $sql . " " . $this->db->mysqli->error);

                }else{
                    $this->int_campaign_id = $this->db->mysqli->insert_id;

            }  

          }
            .....
```

the button:

```
     <?php $camp = new Campaign();
                         $campaign_id2 = $camp->int_campaign_id;

                        ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo site_url('business_campaigns/player_preview');?>?id=<?php echo $campaign_id2;?>" name=""  id=""  class="previewBtn2"> 
           </a>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated,
Mike

Comment: If you're using MySQLi, you really should be using bind variables with prepared statements.... but is your class called `MyClass` or `Campaign`? and where are you actually calling the `Insert()` method?

Comment: side comment: Hi can I get where did you find codeigniter using mysqli?

Comment: it's called Campaign!

Comment: calling the Insert method will run the whole insert function won't it?

Comment: Yes, calling the Insert method will run the whole Insert method, doing the Insert and setting the id value if successful, throwing the exception if not: not calling it won't run it at all

Comment: It's sorted now, I changed the precedence of things for the events and found a better way. Thanks for all the replies!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what variable name you use for your MySQL connection. But `$|connection variable|->insert_id` should get the id you just inserted.

Have you read the [PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php)?

I also recommend using prepared statements to prevent SQL injections.

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling `$camp->insert(...args...)` after making an object of Campaign, in your button code.
It should be

```
<?php
    $camp = new Campaign();
    $camp->insert(...args...)
    $campaign_id2 = $camp->int_campaign_id;
...
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. But wouldn't that run the whole insert method again?

Comment: Creating a obj does not run the insert method. You have to call it and give it parameters.

Comment: i forgot to mention, that there are 2 buttons, one that inserts the campaign, and the other is for the Preview, which is the one in question.

Comment: Sorry, I am not able to understand. Either-way, when you want to insert, create an obj like you did here, call its insert method, then use the same obj($camp) and use obj->campaign_id in the second code-snippet you provided.

Comment: that's my problem, the insert method is being called in another php file via ajax. How do I return the insert_id from that file it's the plroblem

Comment: What is the AJAX call returning? If you are directly sending html from the AJAX call, you can send the campaign_id as a hidden element with a specific ID and using JavaScript, fetch it and you can attach it to the <a> tag(you have to give an ID to the <a> tag).